# PHP Getting a value form a form in POST that has values from a PHP script

Tags: php, forms, post

I created some PHP code to get values from a database and show them as an option in a form I created using HTML. Now I want to be able to select one of those options and then process that in POST. But it gives me an error that my index is undefined when I try to get that value in POST. So I guess my question is, is getting this value possible? If so, how would I accomplish this?

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="dayzconfigedit.php">
<select name="item1">;
    <?php
        //Display the Items from the database in a dropdown menu
        $sql = "SELECT item_id FROM `all_items`";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        for($x = 0; $x < $result->num_rows; $x++) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            echo "<option value=\"{$row["item_id"]}\">{$row["item_id"]}</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Then I try to get value in POST:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    //Grab Selected Items from Form
    $item1 = "$_POST[item1]";
}
```

Thanks in advance!

I skimmed through the post that supposedly answers my question but I still can't solve this issue because I don't know why the index is undefined in the POST array.

Comment: `<select name="item1">;
//Display the Items from the database in a dropdown menu` - You do have a `<?php` opening tag, right? If not, then you're injecting HTML into PHP here.

Comment: Yes, I added the form to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab item 1 like this;

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    //Grab Selected Items from Form
    $item1 = ! empty($_POST['item1']) ? $_POST['item1'] : null;
}
```

Also, please update where you echo the option to be;

```
echo"<option value=\"{$row["item_id"]}\">{$row["item_id"]}</option>";
```

Comment: This removed the error but I still am not getting the value from my form.

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Simon, I thought this would fix it but sadly I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: What results do you get if you add die(var_dump($_POST)); straight after if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

Comment: It tells me that the array is empty.

Comment: I figured it out! It was because I had two forms on the page. I needed to move the submit button into the form with my select tag in it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may either missed to specify `method="post"` in form tag .. or  you missed to specify the name of the field `<select>` tag like `<select name="item1">`.

Now you can access the submitted value in `$_POST["item1"]`

Comment: Yah, I missed that. But even after adding that into my form it still throws the same error.

Comment: could you please show the html form in question

Comment: Yes, I added the form to the inital post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not well versed in PHP but i think your code should read

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    //Grab Selected Items from Form
    $item1 = $_POST["item1"]; //Take note of this line
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I tried this change but it made no difference. I still received the error.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code for the form

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already solved my problem. I had to move my submit button as it was in the wrong form tag. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Alright congrats